# Apache beam dataframe write csv to GCS without shard name template

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Dataflow pipeline using Apache Beam dataframe, and I'd like to write the csv to a GCS bucket. This is my code:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    df = p | read_csv(known_args.input)
    df[column] = df.groupby(primary_key)[column].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()))
    df.to_csv(known_args.output, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

However, while I pass a gcs path to `known_args.output`, the written csv on gcs is added with shard, like this `gs://path/to/file-00000-of-00001`. For my project, I need the file name to be without the shard. I've read the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.33.0/apache_beam.dataframe.frames.html#apache_beam.dataframe.frames.DeferredDataFrame.to_csv) but there seems to be no options to remove the shard. I tried converting the df back to pcollection and use `WriteToText` but it doesn't work either, and also not a desirable solution.

Comment: I'm just wondering, this doesn't seem a use case to use Apache beam. You can use a cloud function for example or a simple python script to handle this use case. If your input CSV is too bigger, and you want to process it, I would suggest to reconsider using dataframe as it consumes too much memory

Comment: @Idhem yeah our CSVs are too big for cloud function, and I simplified the code here but there's a groupby step that I need to use beam dataframe for.

Comment: The first time I started developing with beam, I had a bunch of data that I wanted to deduplicate. First approach came to my mind is using dataframes (coming from python background). Later, with my data kept growing in size, I faced many issues, memory, beam processing approaches, etc. So I changed my approach. My advice, whatever use case you have, make sure to build it using pcollections and transformatiosn. Try to avoid as much as you can dataframes because they consume much memory. They are not valid in the big data field

Comment: Beam's Dataframes parallelize the data under the hood using PCollections; it's common that all the data won't fit into a single dataframe (using, e.g., vanilla Pandas) but it should work with Beam. If there are memory issues here, I would suggest filing a bug at https://github.com/apache/beam/issues

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're right; in Beam 2.40 there's no way to customize the sharding of these dataframe write operations. Instead, you'll have to use convert to a PCollection and use `WriteToText(..., shard_name_template='')`

I filed [BEAM-22923](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/22923). When the relevant [PR](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/22925) is merged this fixed will allow one to pass an explicit file naming parameter (which will allow customization of this as well as windowing information), e.g.

```
df.to_csv(
    output_dir,
    num_shards=1,
    file_naming=fileio.single_file_naming('out.csv'))
```

.

Comment: this is wonderful thank you so much! do you know when the pr will be merged? :)

Comment: Just merged it.