# GroupByKey to fill values and then ungroup apache beam

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have csv files that have missing values per groups formed by primary keys (for every group, there's only 1 value populated for 1 field, and I need that field to be populated for all records of the group). I'm processing the entire file with apache beam and therefore, I want to use `GroupByKey` to fill up the field for each group, and then ungroup it to restore the original data, now with filled data. The equivalent in pandas would be:

```
dataframe[column_to_be_filled] = dataframe.groupby(primary_key)[column_to_be_filled].ffill().bfill()
```

I don't know how to achieve this with apache beam. I first used apache beam dataframe, but that'd take a lot of memory.

Comment: have you tried using Beam's dataframes feature?

Comment: I have, but it consumed a lot of memory hence not desirable. Also they fixed the sharding for csv name output but it hasnt been released yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73498119/apache-beam-dataframe-write-csv-to-gcs-without-shard-name-template

Comment: Could you expand on "consumed a lot of memory"? Was it not properly parallelizing things?

Answer (score 3):

It's better to process your elements with a pcollection instead of a dataframe to avoid memory issues.

First read your CSV as a pcollection and then you can use `GroupByKey` and process the grouped elements and yield the results with a separate transformation.

It could be something like this

```
(pcollection | 'Group by key' >> beam.GroupByKey()
                    | 'Process grouped elements' >> beam.ParDo(UngroupElements()))
```

The input pcollection should be list of tuples each one contains the key you want to group with and the element.

And the ptransformation would look like this:

```
class UngroupElements(beam.ParDo):
    
    def process(element):
        k, v = element
        for elem in list(v):
            # process your element 
            yield elem
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use exactly the same code as Pandas in Beam: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/

You can use `read_csv` to read your data into a dataframe, and then apply the same code that you would use in Pandas. Not all Pandas operations are supported (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/differences-from-pandas/), but that specific case with the group by key should work.