# How to save CSV file using deferred dataframe from Beam SDK or using beam.io.WriteToText() locally?

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am trying to run a pipeline using Direct Runner to save csv files locally, when using to_csv() function from the deferred dataframe it saves file with a string attached to it, I tried using converting to PColl and save it locally with WriteToText() method as a workaround [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73498119/apache-beam-dataframe-write-csv-to-gcs-without-shard-name-template#new-answer), I get csv file populated with data I didn't expect.

```
      with beam.Pipeline(options=OPTIONS) as P:

            dataframe = P | "Read CSV files" >> read_csv(input_path+filename)
            # dataframe.plot() #! Plotting tools not supported yet
            dataframe = dataframe[["time_close", "rate_close"]]
            filename = filename.split('.')[0]
            # WARNING: this saves a shard with file name, trying a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73498119/apache-beam-dataframe-write-csv-to-gcs-without-shard-name-template#new-answer
            # dataframe.to_csv(output_path+filename)
            pcoll =  to_pcollection(dataframe, include_indexes=False) 
            #? Doesn't work
            pcoll | beam.io.WriteToText(output_path+filename, file_name_suffix=".csv", shard_name_template="")
```

```
BeamSchema_0165f459_bb25_47df_897f_00e1eb0f1d09(time_close='2021-08-30T00:59:00.0000000Z', rate_close=48391.24019040889)
BeamSchema_0165f459_bb25_47df_897f_00e1eb0f1d09(time_close='2021-08-30T01:59:00.0000000Z', rate_close=48538.4976211016)
BeamSchema_0165f459_bb25_47df_897f_00e1eb0f1d09(time_close='2021-08-30T02:59:00.0000000Z', rate_close=48461.99016055076)
BeamSchema_0165f459_bb25_47df_897f_00e1eb0f1d09(time_close='2021-08-30T03:59:00.0000000Z', rate_close=48032.02788175993)
```

Edit:
[Bruno Volpato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695821/bruno-volpato)

Tried Bruno's suggestion now I get data in tabular format but not complete data is written:

```
                        time_close    rate_close
0     2021-08-30T00:59:00.0000000Z  48391.240190
1     2021-08-30T01:59:00.0000000Z  48538.497621
2     2021-08-30T02:59:00.0000000Z  48461.990161
3     2021-08-30T03:59:00.0000000Z  48032.027882
4     2021-08-30T04:59:00.0000000Z  47894.899101
...                            ...           ...
8756  2022-08-29T20:59:00.0000000Z  20181.288385
8757  2022-08-29T21:59:00.0000000Z  20213.004179
8758  2022-08-29T22:59:00.0000000Z  20193.586616
8759  2022-08-29T23:59:00.0000000Z  20295.233397
8760  2022-08-30T00:00:00.0000000Z  20287.470353

[8761 rows x 2 columns]
```

Edit: Final edit to this post, what I wanted to do was fairly simple, create a pipeline that select two columns from a CSV file and then apply some modification and save it to different location.

```
        with beam.Pipeline(options=OPTIONS) as P:

            dataframe = P | "Read CSV files" >> read_csv(input_path+filename)
            # dataframe.plot() #! Plotting tools not supported yet
            dataframe = dataframe[["time_close", "rate_close"]]
            (     to_pcollection(dataframe, include_indexes=False, yield_elements='pandas') 
                  | "Modify Timestamp" >> beam.Map(modify_timestamp)
                  | "Save as CSV files" >> beam.io.WriteToText(output_path+filename.split('.')[0], file_name_suffix='.csv', shard_name_template="")
            )
```

It doesn't work as expected(it runs with warnings), instead I get:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  row.loc[:, ['time_close']] = [time[:-1] for time in row['time_close']]
```

So what I'm left with is same as before, a view instead of complete data, I think this is something that is not implemented yet? I had to convert back and forth between pcollection and dataframe, not complaining but if anyone can help with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [documentation for to_pcollection](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.dataframe.convert.html#apache_beam.dataframe.convert.to_pcollection).
By default, `to_pcollection` returns a schema-aware PCollection, which are the `BeamSchema_*` that you are receiving.

One option is to use `yield_elements='pandas'` to have a PCollection with raw values.

Comment: Thanks it worked partially, now I get a data in tabular format but the data itself is incomplete, out of 9000 rows of data I only got 10 rows with ... ... ... in middle like an overview of the data.

Comment: Are you writing over the same file? Maybe try `num_shards=1` on your WriteToText

Comment: Added `num_shards=1`  still same, no I am using same names for the files but different folders.

Comment: In the first example, you are directly writing Beam elements with Schema (NamedTuples) to files. Instead, try extracting fields from NamedTuple elements using a DoFn (or a Beam Map transform) before writing.